# What is the difference between libssl.so.3 and libssl3.so?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I've been playing with uprobes to attach to SSL sym, checked the libraries available in my OS (Manjaro kernel v5.15.89) and found both of these library files:

```
❯ ls -l /lib64/libssl3.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 420208 Jan  6 14:54 /lib64/libssl3.so
❯ ls -l /lib64/libssl.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 651008 Dec 14 14:22 /lib64/libssl.so.3
```

What is the difference between libssl.so.3 and libssl3.so?

Comment: This reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319) question; what issues are you facing that lead you to asking this question? If this is just about basic curiosity, please clearly state that. Otherwise, if there is another issue you are attempting to deal with, please add details on that to your question.

Comment: I believe they are different products. my hunch is that `libssl.so.3` is a component of OpenSSL v3, whereas `libssl3.so` is kernel support for the old insecure SSLv3 protocol. OpenSSL supports many different protocols (like TLS).

Comment: Thanks the comments. @Giacomo1968, it is just a curiosity. I've just updated the question!

Comment: Perhaps `/lib64/libssl.so.3` is part of `mozilla-nss`. At least on `opensuse`, `/usr/lib64/libssl3.so` is. Your package manager will be able to tell you.

Comment: On CentOS 7, `/usr/lib64/libssl3.so` comes from the `nss` package (as determined by the `yum whatprovides /usr/lib64/libssl3.so` command).